# How to run Cron Job command every minute between 11PM to 3AM?

Tags: cron, cpanel

How can I run cron Job command every minute between 11PM to 3AM?

My Code:

```
*   23-2    *   *   *   [command]
```

I tried many solutions but my problem is this error:

> You did not format the date and time settings correctly.

Note: I work on Cpanel on godaddy.

Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have extra spaces or tabs in your command. Try using `* 23-02 * * * command`.

Comment: @l'L'l I checked, it's not the problem.

Comment: I don't think it allows ranges to wrap out of the end of the sequence, in this case from 23 to 0. Try using `0-2,23` in the hours field.  If that doesn't work then try `0,1,2,23`.